# Angular 5 No provider for Window

Tags: angular

My Angular 5 app is building fine with `npm start`, but when I navigate to a particular component in Chrome, I'm getting this cryptic error in the console. I can't find a single mention of it in search.

(I'm trying to upgrade this component from Angular 4 to Angular 5.)

```
core.js:1350 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[Window]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Window]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Window!
Error: StaticInjectorError[Window]: 
  StaticInjectorError[Window]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Window!
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:923)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10584)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:11805)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10584)
    at _NullInjector.get (core.js:923)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveToken (core.js:1211)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:1153)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:1024)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10584)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:11805)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:10584)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:824)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:795)
    at eval (zone.js:873)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:425)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4617)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:192)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:602)
    at <anonymous>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `module.ts`. This error says you have used `window` but it is not defined in your `module.ts` Provider.

Example:

```
providers: [
    Window
],
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was coming from a component test file. I rebuilt my node_modules, restarted the editor (VS Code), and the error went away. I didn't need to add any provider for window.

Comment: This is always a good idea when upgrading angular, delete node_modules folder, check package.Json and npm i again. Package.lock.json can also cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had to declare as in:

```
providers: [ { provide: "Window", useValue: window } ],
```

That's because I'm using it within a specific service that depends on Window injection, and then I create a custom window value extending itself.